# Android app that emulates browser to run web app

Tags: android, web-applications, emulation

I couldn´t find my exact question here. So: How is it possible to code an Android app which only emulates a browser window (without url bar and stuff) and starts a web app?

I didn´t begin coding because I want to know if that is possible.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you need to use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) for this.

Follow [Building Web Apps in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)